# How to fetch more than 1000 records in parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

Iam trying to query the parse using javascript.As we have limit to fetch 1000 records per query.What is the best alternative to fetch more than 1000 records in parse.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/GmIt3OG2m8o it appears that this scenario is covered in detail by this post. In short you'll need to page through the query results 1000 at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This questions should help you:

[Parse - retrieve more then 1000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246991/parse-retrieve-more-then-1000-rows)

[How to get more than 1000 results Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688005/how-to-get-more-than-1000-results-parse?rq=1)

Obs: duplicated question. flagging.